# DBRef not fetched when saving object

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using DBRef of an ObjectB in another ObjectA. I would like to fetch ObjectB when saving ObjectA with a partial ObjectB (understand here that ObjectB contains only its id when I save ObjectA)

When I execute this junit test, I can see that the DBRef is not fetched when saving ObjectA. But when I make a query, I retrieve the values.

```
    ObjectB objB = new ObjectB("name");

    //Using constructor with (name)
    objB = objectBRepo.save(objB);
    //Using constructor with (id, name)
    partialObjB partialObjB = new ObjectB(objB.getId(), null);

    ObjectA objectA = new ObjectA(partialObjB);
    objectASaved = repo.save(objectA);

    objectAQueried = objectARepo.findOne(objectAWithoutFetch);

    assertNotNull("Name should be defined", objectAQueried.getObjectB().getName());
    assertNotNull("Name should be defined", objectASaved.getObjectB().getName());
```

The second assert failed.

Is it a normal behaviour ? Should I query the object every time when I just saved it ?

Comment: Normal behavior. DBRefs don't cause the referred object to be saved in the referring object - think about how troublesome this would be for updates to the referred object.

Comment: Thanks @wdberkeley : I can understand that referred object should not be saved in the referring object, but I could expect that the data would be refreshed and return by the save method...

Comment: It's unclear what's happening just from your code and I can't tell what you're expecting. Are you saving a [DBRef](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-types/#database-references) or a partial object? What do the actual documents looks like? A DBRef is a driver-side concept that's a way to encode a reference to a document; it's up to the driver if/when/how it resolves the reference into the referent at query time (not at insert time)